# Why does Steam sort by playtime incorrectly?

Tags: steam

When going to the games list on my steam profile, and selecting to sort by playtime, http://steamcommunity.com/my/games/?tab=all&sort=playtime I get a list that looks like this.[image] As you can see 5 games are highlighted and placed at the top of the list for some reason. Why are those games highlighted and moved up top?

It's not recently played games, because I haven't played WFTO in a couple months, and haven't yet played Pillars of Eternity at all.

Comment: My list is sorted just fine, no highlighted games either.

Comment: Is it recently downloaded/updated?

Comment: I think it may be a subtle hint that you have to spend some hours in the real world as well. You know - clouds, grass, waterfalls, mountains, steppes, significant others.

Comment: Consider this a subtle hint that neener neener neener you can't make me!... I messed up the subtle part didn't I? Also, that sounds like Minecraft with a Waifu mod to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jersh stated in comments, that indicates a game that has been recently downloaded or updated.

[image]